# Create new object and write to file with fs.writeFile()

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, fs

**There are two things I want to do:**

I want to create a new array of objects from an existing object,

And increment the object so each object can have a count id of 1,2,3 etc

My issue is that when I write to the file it writes only 1 random object to the file and the rest don't show. There are so errors and all the objects have the same increment value. Please explain what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

### **Code:**

#### **data.json:**

```
{  
   "users":[  
      {  
         "name":"mike",       
         "category":[  
            {  
               "title":"cook",
            }
         ],
         "store":{  
            "location":"uptown",
            "city":"ulis"
         },
         "account":{  
            "type":"regular", 
            "payment":[  
               "active":false
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

#### **index.js:**

```
const appData = ('./data.json')
const fs = require('fs');
let newObject = {}



appData.forEach(function(items){

        let x = items
        let  numincrement = 1++

        newObject.name = x.name
        newObject.count =  numincrement
        newObject.categories =  x.categories
        newObject.store =  x.store
        newObject.account = x.account 

        fs.writeFile('./temp.json', JSON.stringify(newObject, null, 2),'utf8' , function(err, data) {
            // console.log(data)
            if(err) { 

                console.log(err)
                return
            } else{
                console.log('created')
            }
          })
    })
```

Comment: What do you want in the JSON file?  A single object?  All the objects in an array of objects?  `fs.writeFile()` rewrites the entire file.  It does not append to the file.  And, you can't append JSON anyway.

Comment: i want all the object in the array in a file that i can maybe appenn in the future

Comment: There are multiple things wrong here.  Is started writing an answer, but then deleted it because it's unclear what your desired result is.  If you clarify, I can finish my answer an undelete it.  Thing I noticed to start with: 1) You need to create a new instance of `newObject` in the loop rather than reuse the same one.  2) You need to move `numincrement` outside the loop so it's value persists from one iteration to the next, 3) You need to answer the above question in my first comment and change the way you write the results.

Comment: Well, you can't "append" to JSON.  That's now how the JSON format works.  If you want to add to the existing JSON, you have to read the existing JSON, parse it, add to it's structure, convert to JSON, rewrite it to the file.

Comment: i will worry about the appending part later i just want to make sure i can write the objects to a file for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of problems here:

1. You're just rewriting the same object over and over to the file.  `fs.writeFile()` rewrites the entire file.  It does not append to the file.  In addition, you cannot append to the JSON format either.  So, this code will only every write one object to the file.
2. To append new JSON data to what's in the existing file, you would have to read in the existing JSON, parse it to convert it to a Javascript array, then add new items onto the array, then convert back to JSON and write out the file again.  For more efficient appending, you would need a different data format (perhaps comma delimited lines).
3. Your loop has all sorts of problems.  You're assigning to the same `newObject` over and over again.
4. Your `numincrement` is inside the loop so it will have the same value on every invocation of the loop.  You can also just use the `index` parameter passed to the `forEach()` callback instead of using your own variable.
5. If what you're trying to iterate over is the `users` array in your data, then you may need to be iterating over `appData.users`, not just `appData`.

---

If you really just want to append data to a text file, the JSON is not the easiest format to use.  It might be easier to just use comma delimited lines.  Then, you can just append new lines to the file.  Can't really do that with JSON.

---

If you're willing to just overwrite the file with the current data, you can do this:

```
const appData = ('./data.json').users;
const fs = require('fs');

// create an array of custom objects
let newData = appData.map((item, index) => {
    return {
        name: item.name,
        count: index + 1,
        categories: item.categoies,
        store: item.store,
        account: item.account
    };
});
// write out that data to a file as JSON (overwriting existing file)
fs.writeFile('./temp.json', JSON.stringify(newData, null, 2),'utf8' , function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("data written");
    }
});
```

Comment: @obumoon - I added an implementation that just writes out the existing array of objects to the file (no appending).